# Warning: Functions in interfaces should be declared external

Tags: solidity

I have a following interface function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface myInterface {

function registerUser(string memory email) public
      return (bool success);
}

contract myContract is myInterface {
    function registerUser(string memory email) public
      return (bool success){
         //some code ...
      }
    }
}
```

When I compile the smart contract using `solc`, I get following warning message:

```
Warning: Functions in interfaces should be declared external.
    function registerUser(string memory email,
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Later, based on following [link](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/issues/809#issuecomment-377725345)'s recommendation, I have replaces `public` keyword with `external` and obtained following error message:

```
Error: Location has to be calldata for external functions (remove the "memory" or "storage" keyword).
    function registerUser(string memory email,
```

---

After I have replaced `public` keyword with `external` keyword, I have obtained
following error message.

```
Error: Function overload clash during conversion to external types for arguments.
    function registerUser(string email,
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this warning message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Function overload clash during conversion to external types for
>   arguments.

For this error make sure you also define it external when calling from another contract.
because belove code works fine without any error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface myInterface {

function registerUser(string email) external
      returns (bool success);
}

contract myContract is myInterface {
    function registerUser(string  email) external
      returns (bool success){
         //some code ...
      }
    }
```

Comment: Original function actually takes more than one argument, that's why it causes following error after I made the changes,: `Compiler error: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.`; I guess I have to stick to warning message.